# How to keep graphic render working in remote desktop?

Tags: windows, remote-desktop, gpu, graphics

I use remote desktop to connect to my home pc for gaming. The problem is that when I minimize/close my remote desktop connection, the game would crash. I tried some solutions (e.g. https://knowledge.civilgeo.com/knowledge-base/enabling-gpu-rendering-for-microsoft-remote-desktop/) about enabling RemoteFX. It worked perfectly at the beginning. Yet if I minimize the connection for a certain amount of time, the GPU rendering would be gone and the game would still crash. If I keep the remote desktop connection as my foreground window, then it works perfectly. My question is: is there any way I can keep the GPU rendering for remote desktop even if I minimize it? Thanks!

Comment: Are you ok with using another service? Remote desktop essentially opens its own 'new' desktop session, which gets logged out if you disconnect. Something that captures the 'screen' output directly like parsec would work better here